# AVERAGEIF after operation within array formula

Tags: excel

Say I have three columns of data:

```
A       B     C
2       10    Cat
3       12    Dog
2       13    Cat
```

I want average C for value `Cat` using:

```
=averageif(C:C,"Cat",B:B)
```

However, I would like to first perform an operation on column B and then calculate the average.  I'm just drawing a blank on how to get the array to work.  I want something like this:

```
{=averageif(C:C, "Cat", B:B/A:A*5)}
```

This of course doesn't work. I could make an extra column, but I would like to do this with a function if possible.

Is there a way to perform an array operation and then use AVERAGEIF, ie array manipulation and then calculate the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array version of `AVERAGE` (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=AVERAGE(IF(C:C="Cat",B:B/A:A*5))
```

You should avoid using full column references in this version.

Comment: This is perfect thanks!  For some reason I couldn't remember how to order it with the array.